# Sharepoint Service 3.0: Extract user information from Active Directory

Tags: active-directory, sharepoint, sharepoint-services

I’m working on my companies Sharepoint Intranet site which runs on a Sharepoint Service 3.0. Everything works fine except one thing.

I want to create a sort of employee list with all the information about the employee, like phone, e-mail, name, position in the company, etc. The thing is, that all that information already are in our Active Directory, so I want to extract that data and create the employee list from the AD instead of writing it all down again. Furthermore, it would be to great help regarding updates and maintenance of the employees that it only changes has to occur in the AD.

I hope I’ve explained my problem correctly otherwise, please let me know.

Sincere
Mestika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you are talking about Sync AD information to SharePoint list to me.

I encountered the same issue before. I was advised that SharePoint (SharePoint 2007 in my case)build in features offer such functionality, but I did not even close to that end by using build in features. That is why I end up using third party tool like [SharePoint AD Sync](http://www.sharepointboost.com/ad-sync.html)(which is 30-day free, by the way).

Just for your information.

Answer (score 0):

For 2007 I suspect [this](http://sharepointnotes.wordpress.com/2008/05/05/syncing-wss-and-moss-user-profile-properties-with-active-directory/) may work though I haven't tried. The there are a number of web parts available on the web for Employee Directories which sounds like what you want.

I'm looking for a similar thing for Sharepoint 2010 however my understanding is that for that you need a version of Share Point Server Portal with the user profile sync service. For Sharepoint 2010 this includes standard and enterprise ( http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee721049.aspx ) so be careful if you upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

You can extract your data out of the AD using either LDIFDE (in xml format) or CSVDE (for output in csv). You can specify which records to dump and fields you want to extract also...

Good site here for details:

http://www.computerperformance.co.uk/Logon/CSVDE_LDIFDE.htm

Answer (score 0):

Write a PowerShell script that gets all the users from AD and then pushes the data into a list. One thing I have done in the past is write a PowerShell script that queries a SQL Server DB, purgese the SharePoint (WSS 3.0) list of all data and then pushes the current data to the list. It can be run on a schedule use Scheduled Tasks. I'd be more than willing to assist if this seems like it would be the way you want to go.

Here is some example code for the WSS 3.0 side:

```
[void][System.reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("Microsoft.SharePoint")
$site    =     new-object Microsoft.SharePoint.SPSite("https://portal.domain.com/")
$web     =    $Site.OpenWeb("rfq") 
$list    =    $web.Lists["Estimating_Load"]

$items = $list.Items;
#Purge the list.
for ($i=$items.Count -1; $i -ge 0; $i -= 1) 
{
    $items.Delete($i);
}

##Add new items to list.
foreach($dataitem in $DataSet.Tables[0])
{

        $newitem =    $list.items.Add()

        $newitem["Customer"]     = $dataitem.Company;                                                                                          
        $newitem["Quote_Number"] = $dataitem.Quote_No;                                                                                          
        $newitem["Sales_Person"] = $dataitem.Sales_Person;
        $newitem["Estimator"]    = $dataitem.Estimator;
        $newitem["Due_Date"]     = $dataitem.Due_Date;
        $newitem["Time"]         = $dataitem.TimeToCompEa;

        $newitem.update()  
}
$web.Dispose()
$site.Dispose()
```